# How to fix "new property name: Aborted" error when make:entity command finishes?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-console

I would like to make Doctrine entity via Symfony 4 console command

```
php bin/console make:entity article
```

The command creates the entity and repository file but it does not allow me to add fields to the entity. Command ends up with an error:

> New property name (press  to stop adding fields): Aborted.

What does it mean? How can I solve it? PHP 7.4 Win 10 Doctrine 2

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? On what platform? What version of Symfony?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does PHP 7.4 on Windows aborts all command line actions that require user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403264/why-does-php-7-4-on-windows-aborts-all-command-line-actions-that-require-user-in)

Comment: Doctrine version is irrelevant. Notice that I asked about _Symfony_ version. In any case, the problem is a bug in 7.4 on windows. You don't mention the **patch** version, which is important, but upgrading is the solution for this issue.

Comment: Yes it could be the problem. Update is not so easy cause I must update whole wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with an uppercase. You should also check wether your database is associated correctly in your `.env` file with the right port.

Something like this:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
```